# Removed all Nvidia drivers and Ubuntu won't boot

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

I installed a new Raedon R9 290X after upgrading from my old Nvidia GTX 570, installed the AMD Catalyst 14.6 drivers and everything booted fine but games where a little laggy. 
I decided to remove the old Nvidia drivers by running

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

After this I could no longer boot as it can no longer detect my display drivers and won't even enter "low graphics mode", although the screen to allow the option appears. Viewing the config files return nothing, the files are empty according to the screen. I can still access the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that no amount of repair or re-installing or unnistalling drivers was helping. Couldn't even load default open source drivers. Instead I loaded up a LiveCD to backup all my files and did a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

First off I'm a R9-290X user.

For ubuntu 16.04+, use the latest Mesa drivers from here:
https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

It works a LOT better than the AMDGPU-Pro with the GCN 1.1 architecture of the R9-290X; that's in reference to games.  Well at the time of this writing anyway.

I've used it to play Tom Raider, MM 2033/LL Redux and Shadow of Mordor at the highest settings coupled with an i7-3770.